# Hose Reel Problems

Tags: hoses

I bought a house that came with a hose reel - they left it behind. But I can't imagine it's broken as it seems so simple.

I added a picture - but it's not the one I have. Basically though the hoses work and are not kinked or clogged but no water comes out to the long hose from what I circled in red. All you get out of that connect is drops.

Any ideas?

[image: Hose reel example]

Answer (score 4):

Hose reels can and do go bad, though yours sounds somewhat atypical. Usually water sprays everywhere (except out the hose) as the rotating seals fail.

1. Diagnostic one - remove the 2 foot hose from the reel - does water
   flow from the faucet to the end of the 2 foot hose? Mud wasps or
   various other things can plug up even a very short hose.
2. Diagnostic two - with water out the short hose, remove the long hose
       from the reel and see if water comes out the the connector on the
       reel - same issues.
3. Diagnostic three - check that water flows through the long hose when
       connected directly to the faucet.

If you pass all those, then it should work with the hose on the reel. If you don't, you'll have a better idea where to look.

Comment: I found out that no water comes out of the hose connector on the reel. So from the faucet, to the connector hose is fine. But from the reel itself also has another connector. Nothing comes out.